# Adding an icon at top level in order to backtrack up an Oracle Tree hierachy

Tags: sql, tree, oracle-apex

I am using the following Oracle tree query within Oracle APEX:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0 when level = 1 then 1 else -1 end as status,
       level,
       ENAME as title
       NULL  as icon,
       EMPNO as value,
       ENAME as tooltip,
       NULL  as link
from EMP
start with MGR = :MGR
connect by prior EMPNO = MGR
order siblings by ENAME
```

I basically want to be able to add an icon as my top link in order to provide a user a means of returning back up the tree, if they are, say 4 levels down.

I would like to use the above query as the base to also display an icon as part of the tree.

Comment: You want to display icon as root of the tree, and all tree will under this icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using jQuery .prepend() to create my root node icon of tree.